# How do I take ballistics in mind?

Tags: the-hunter

I heard about 'zeroing' the weapon but didn't see a way to do it. Then probably I should adjust my aim during the game. What are adjustements I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer at Steam forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/253710/discussions/0/618458030684398342/) all rifles are zeroed at 100m distance.

The bullet speed is a number that I can't find in wiki and that probably differs from one rifle to another, but lets assume it passes 100m in 300msec and we shoot horizontally, so the bullet falls 0.5m towards the ground at that distance. Then since we are looking 25cm below the horizontal line at the distance of 50m and the bullet is only 12.5cm down there, then the adjustment (the height we should add to the dot we want to hit) is -12.5cm. In case of 200m distance we look 1m below the horizontal line while the bullet is 2m down, then the adjustment should be +1m.

Here is how I came to this: [image]

**UPDATE 1:** but at shooting range I see that the bullet hits exactly where I aim, no matter if it's 30m away or 130m

**UPDATE 2:** while gravity seems to have no impact on riffles, bow's arrow really goes down as I saw it at range. And now when faced Roosevelt Elk the first time my riffle didn't work, because I had 0 ammo. So I had to use a bow.

[image]

Here I marked with the yellow circle where I aimed -- arrow went a bit "left" because Elk immediately started running. You see here, that arrow went down 50-75cm during 50m flight. P.S.: brain is damaged because it didn't die -- he was running for a while and then just stopped to wait me to finish him ..(